# Recursive function - how to extract only children with specific value in a class with several levels

Tags: c#, recursion, static-methods

I have a Region class with property of RegionType. RegionType can be "country", "multi city", "city", "neighborhood" and more. on any given Region, i would like to extract all neighborhoods, so on Thailand i expect to get Bangkok, Samui etc. becuase they are cities, i need to go down another level - how can i do this recursively? I tried to create recursive static method that look like this:

```
public static List<Region> GetNeighborhoods(this Region region, ref List<Region> neighborhoods)
{

    var ctx = new DalContext();

    if (region.RegionType == "Country" || 
        region.RegionType == "Multi-Region (within a country)" || 
        region.RegionType == "City" ||
        region.RegionType == "Multi-City (Vicinity)" || 
        region.RegionType == "Province (State)" || 
        region.RegionType == "Multi-Region (within a country)")
    {
        IEnumerable<Region> childrens = region.GetChildren();

        if (childrens.Any())
        {
            foreach (var child in childrens)
            {
                return GetNeighborhoods(child, ref neighborhoods);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        neighborhoods.AddRange(ctx.Regions
                               .Where(r => r.ParentRegionId == region.ParentRegionId 
                                      && r.RegionType == "Neighborhood" 
                                      && r.RegionNameLong.Contains(region.RegionName) 
                                      && r.Id != region.Id).ToList());
    }

    return neighborhoods;
}
```

ctx is my DB instance with all regions.
at the end of the run i get 0 regions in neighborhoods list.
Help??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would probably be better off turning this into a method that returns an `IEnumerable<Region>`.

Without having definitions for all your classes I can't check the validity of this, but something along these lines should work:

```
public static IEnumerable<Region> GetNeighborhoods(Region region)
{
    if 
    (
        region.RegionType == "Country" || 
        region.RegionType == "Multi-Region (within a country)" || 
        region.RegionType == "City" ||
        region.RegionType == "Multi-City (Vicinity)" || 
        region.RegionType == "Province (State)" || 
        region.RegionType == "Multi-Region (within a country)"
    )
    {
        foreach (var child in region.GetChildren())
            foreach (var region in GetNeighborhoods(child))
                yield return region;
    }
    else
    {
        var ctx = new DalContext();

        var matchingRegions = ctx.Regions.Where(r => 
            r.ParentRegionId == region.ParentRegionId && 
            r.RegionType == "Neighborhood" &&
            r.RegionNameLong.Contains(region.RegionName) && 
            r.Id != region.Id
        );

        foreach (var region in matchingRegions)
            yield return region;
    }
}
```

However, I have no idea what that `DalContext()` is doing, so it might completely fail in that area...

Comment: You have Multi-Region twice in the if condition. I also think it's customary to start a recursive function with the end condition.

Comment: @o_weisman I have just copied the OP's code - without knowing exactly what it does I can't make sweeping changes. However, the "end condition" is clearly "no more children", which is of course implicit in the first `foreach`.